# datetaken timestamp (where to find)

Tags: windows, pascal, ntfs

I know NTFS has 3 timestamps: created,modifyed and last access.
So when I have a folder containig JPG-files the major sort-criteria is: datetaken whitch appears to be read in the EXIF of the file.
But as it is the main sort-criteria I cannot believe that Windows-Explorer opens each file to read this EXIF each time I change the folder whith hundreds of pictures just to order its entries. Even there is a file-property decribed by microsoft called SystemDateTaken.

Does anyone know where this datetaken is stored and how to get hold on it (eg. an API-Call)?
I'm working with Windows 7 and pascal (Lazarus)

Comment: Yes, Explorer opens each file to get its EXIF data.

Comment: NTFS actually has [four timestamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364217). The `ChangeTime` is updated for any change, such as changing file attributes or security. The common `WIN32_FIND_DATA` doesn't return this timestamp -- probably because it's always 0 for FAT drives.

Comment: As to an API for accessing properties, you can bind an [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library//bb761144) to an [`IPropertyStore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761474) handler.

Comment: @eryksun do you have an exaplecall (maybe in pascal) as I'm a newbee in Freepascal and specialy in implementing API-Calls there.  - on the other hand I could open all files im Pascal to get this information, even that I think it will make a performance-problem.